# Is it possible to change TableView style based on size classes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have controller which has tableview inside. I want to change that tableview style to be *grouped* on compact and *insetGrouped* on regular devices. I want to use new iOS 13 tableview style whenever user rotates his device to regular size.

```
class myTableVC: UITableViewController {

   init() {
      super.init(style: .grouped)
   }

   override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
      if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
         // CANT DO THIS
         // self.tableview.style = .insetGrouped
      }
   }


}
```

I want to have similar design to settings app. 
Is it possible to change style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style):

> You set the table style when you initialize the table view (see initWithFrame:style:). You cannot modify the style thereafter.

One option would be to embed **two** table views as subviews -- one set to Grouped and one set to Inset Grouped.

Then show/hide the appropriate one based on size class.

Comment: Its correct answer. Having two table views is bad idea, so i ended up with UIViewController with tableview.